# How to transform a list of lists of strings to a frequency DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, data-science

I have a list of lists of strings (Essentially it's a corpus) and I'd like to convert it to a matrix where a row is a document in the corpus and the columns are the corpus' vocabulary.

I can do this with `CountVectorizer` but it would require quite a lot of memory as I would need to convert each list into a string that in turn `CountVectorizer` would tokenize.

I think it's possible to do it with Pandas only but I'm not sure how.

Example:

```py
corpus = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['a', 'a'],['b', 'c', 'c']]
```

expected result:

```
| a | b | c |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
```

Comment: Using `[' '.join(x) for x in corpus]` before count vectorizing doesn't work you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would combine [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from collections import Counter

corpus = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['a', 'a'],['b', 'c', 'c']]

df = pd.DataFrame(map(Counter, corpus)).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  0  0
2  0  1  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using only Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

corpus = pd.DataFrame(corpus).T
corpus_freq = corpus.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).T
corpus_freq = corpus_freq.fillna(0)
```

End result:

```
     a    b    c
 0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1  2.0  0.0  0.0
 2  0.0  1.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
Set =[]
from collections import Counter
for lst in corpus:
    r = dict(Counter(lst).most_common(3))
    Set.append(r)
    
pd.DataFrame(Set).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

which gives:

```
  a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  0  0
2  0  1  2
```